# os.kill not working on spawned process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, kill-process

I have written my own Python-based job scheduler which uses the multiprocessing module, to spawn new jobs.  I'm trying to implement a feature to kill a running process using `os.kill`, but it is not working.  My (simplified) code look like the following:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
...
p = Process(target=self.start_job, args=(run_dir,cmd,))
p.start()
...
def start_job(self,run_dir,cmd):
        os.chdir(run_dir)
        os.system(cmd)
        print os.getpid()
        ...
```

I want to take this pid that is output (e.g. 3064) and from another python session run:

```
import os, signal    
os.kill(3064, signal.SIGTERM)
```

`os.kill` works if I run it on the pid of the parent/spawning process, but it does not work if I execute it on the pid of the child/spawned process.  In addition to SIGTERM, I've also tried a number of other signals such as SIGKILL, SIGQUIT, etc. None of them worked either.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a process group using the `subprocess` module to create the process and using `os.killpg()` to kill the process as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791612/2636544